# CSS flickering on page load because of css delay

Tags: javascript, html, css, delay, blocking

I have a problem with my page:
https://dev.saunashop-saunazubehoer.de/
User: demo / demo

When the page is loading I can see some delay in css - even if it is cached. 
It looks like the Page is fickering for a few milliseconds.

I removed all the JS but still the same error occours.

In the original Shop saunashop-saunazubehoer.de everything works fine.
I added the new bootstrap and updated jquery on so on but I cant really tell the difference.

The error occurs only in Firefox - chrome / IE / Edge is working fine after the css-file is cached.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

Comment: Can you post your code here please (or provide a jsfiddle)?